# Extract all possible sequence from one sequence by circular shift

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering that does there exists one sequence with the length of $m^n$ to generate all possible (in total n) base-m sequences by circular shift?

For example (circular shift observations):

1) 1 1 0 0 can generate 1 1, 1 0, 0 0, 0 1.

2) 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 3 2 can generate 1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 3, 3 3, 3 1, 1 3, 3 2, 2 1

3) 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 can generate 1 1 1, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 1 0 1, 0 1 1

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence

Comment: Thank you！！That is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about De Bruijn sequences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence.